# CMake finds suitable Python version, but cannot use interpreter

Tags: python, linux, cmake, fedora, qgis

I am trying to upgrade QGIS from 3.10 to 3.20 and this requires upgrading CMake to >=3.15 and Python >= 3.7.  I am using an EOL Linux distribution (Fedora 28, upgrading the OS is the obvious easy fix but this has to be done on 28, no questions asked).  I've installed both CMake (3.19.4) and Python (3.7.9) to my local directories, set them to path, and have added the following CMake options:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DWITH_SERVER=ON \
-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/python3.7 -D......
```

yet I receive the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:218 (message):


Could NOT find Python (missing: Python_EXECUTABLE Interpreter) (found
  suitable version "3.7.9", minimum required is "3.7")

      Reason given by package: 
          Interpreter: Cannot use the interpreter "/usr/local/bin/python3.7"

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:582 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake:3148 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPython.cmake:428 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:946 (find_package)
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed?  I've added the flags "-DCMAKE_PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR" and "-DCMAKE_PYTHON_LIBRARY", made sure I configured the local Python to have shared libraries enabled and this either changes nothing or reverts to finding the older Python on my path (3.6.8).

Comment: The message "Cannot use interpreter" means that running given interpreter with [parameters](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake#L724) `-c "import sys; sys.stdout.write('.'.join([str(x) for x in sys.version_info[:3]]))"` **fails** (return non-zero result). You could run the interpreter by yourself and closely inspect error message.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I do get a non-zero result (version info is printed) when running the above, but running test python programs seems to work still.

Comment: Silent returning non-zero looks strange. Just tested, on Ubuntu 20.04 Python 3.8.10 returns 0 for the above code.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've tried with native Python3 (3.6.8) and also get the version returned.  This is Fedora 28 (yes I know it's old but upgrading is not an option right now)

Comment: Hmm, do you check the **result** (more correctly, the **exit code**) or the text **printed**? CMake checks exactly the exit code. The exit code is NOT printed by python. If you run python from the terminal, then you could extract its exit code by following `echo $?`.